# knockoutJS - select default template on init

Tags: templates, knockout.js, default

is it possible to pre-select a template before one will be selected in the menu. For example if I have the following knockoutJS Code: http://jsfiddle.net/rqa8P/15/

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// View
var View = function(page, templateName, data) {
   var self = this;

   self.page = page; 
   self.templateName = templateName;
   self.data = data; 

   //animations between page changes
   this.animatePageChange = function() {
      $('.wrapper').hide(); 
      $('.wrapper').fadeIn(3000);
      //init function for each main menu view model
      //alert(self.data.init());
    };

    //animations between sup page changes
    this.animateSubPageChange = function() {
      $('.content').hide(); 
      $('.content').fadeIn(3000);
      //init function for each sub menu view model
      //alert(self.data.init());
    }
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SubPage1ViewModel (Subpage from Main Page View 1)
var SubPage1ViewModel = {
    init: function() {return("SubPage1ViewModel init")},
    somedata : ko.observable("Here comes some data!")
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SubPage2ViewModel (Subpage from Main Page View 1)
var SubPage2ViewModel = {
    init: function() {return("SubPage2ViewModel init")},
    somedata : ko.observable("Here comes some data!")
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SubPage3ViewModel (Subpage from Main Page View 1)
var SubPage3ViewModel = {
    init: function() {return("SubPage3ViewModel init")},
    somedata : ko.observable("Here comes some data!")
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MainPage1viewModel (Menu Page)
var MainPage1viewModel = {
  //Sub Pages
  subpage1view : new View("subpage1", "subpage1Tmpl", SubPage1ViewModel),
  subpage2view : new View("subpage2", "subpage2Tmpl", SubPage2ViewModel),
  subpage3view : new View("subpage3", "subpage3Tmpl", SubPage3ViewModel),

  //make the selected sub page observable
  selectedView : ko.observable(),

  init: function() {return("MainPage1viewModel init")}
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MainPage2 View (Main Menu)
var MainPage2viewModel = {
    //init function
    init: function() {return("MainPage2viewModel init")},

    somedata : ko.observable("Here comes some data!")
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ControlViewModel (cvm), 
var cvm = {
  //Main Pages
  mainPage1view : new View("mainpage1", "mainPage1Tmpl", MainPage1viewModel),
  mainPage2view : new View("mainpage2", "mainPage2Tmpl", MainPage2viewModel),

  //make the selected page observable
  selectedView : ko.observable(),
};

//bind the cvm view model to the index.html
ko.applyBindings(cvm);
```

My goal is when the page is loaded that the Main Page 2 Template is already loaded into the dom and if I click to the Main Page 1 then it should be immediately loaded with the SubPage1 content. At moment there is always a site before...

greetings!

Comment: mmm not sure I understand what you need here?

Answer (score 0):

You already have selectedView observable, why not put inside pre defined value? You will need to revrite your ViewModel as a constructor to call internal variables with `this` :

```
// ControlViewModel (cvm), 
var cvm = function () {
  //Main Pages
  this.mainPage1view = new View("mainpage1", "mainPage1Tmpl", MainPage1viewModel);
  this.mainPage2view = new View("mainpage2", "mainPage2Tmpl", MainPage2viewModel);

  //make the selected page observable
  this.selectedView = ko.observable(this.mainPage2view);
};

//bind the cvm view model to the index.html
ko.applyBindings( new cvm() );
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rqa8P/16/

Or add selectedView property after declaring ViewModel so you can use cvm.mainPage2view object variable:

```
// ControlViewModel (cvm), 
var cvm = {
  //Main Pages
  mainPage1view : new View("mainpage1", "mainPage1Tmpl", MainPage1viewModel),
  mainPage2view : new View("mainpage2", "mainPage2Tmpl", MainPage2viewModel)
};

//make the selected page observable
cvm.selectedView = ko.observable( cvm.mainPage2view );
```

JSFiddle: ../17/ (can't post more links)

Or just put the value after declaring ViewModel just as any other observable:

```
// ControlViewModel (cvm), 
var cvm = {
  //Main Pages
  mainPage1view : new View("mainpage1", "mainPage1Tmpl", MainPage1viewModel),
  mainPage2view : new View("mainpage2", "mainPage2Tmpl", MainPage2viewModel),

  //make the selected page observable
  selectedView : ko.observable(),
};

cvm.selectedView( cvm.mainPage2view );
```

JSFiddle: ../18/ (can't post more links)

For subpage content do analogically with mainPage1view.selectedView observable.